# Is there a way of making wordpress upload to a specific directory so i can point a javascript script at it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm doing work for a client with wordpress, i'm relatively new to wordpress. They want a gallery that will display images based on what they upload, they're not technologically inclined in the slightest bit. Wordpress seems to upload into different folders for each month and year, i'd like to avoid having to get javascript to plough through x amount of folders every time the page loads.

Things i've tried so far:

1. Using next gen gallery: This works, to a point, the 'responsiveness' of the gallery is not very responsive, it's set images that just wrap, meaning you're left with a large border down one side of the gallery until the screen gets small enough that it then wraps again...
2. Creating my own plugin: I've not done this before and there isn't really enough time for me to have to learn a whole new syntax.
3. Using advanced custom fields: This requires either premium to create a gallery, or adding alot of fields to every page and just checking the field is blank, then exiting the loop.

So, what i would like to do is allow my client to upload into 3 set directories, say Cars, Planes and Boats with different images for each, then on the relevant page, call my javascript function with a parameter for the folder that will then generate the gallery.

Is this possible?
Am i re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default uploads folder for WordPress by adding this to the `wp-config.php` file:

```
require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);
define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/images');
```

Just create whatever sub-directories you need in there and it should be fine.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the response. it sort of works, it allows me to set the folder, but it creates sub directories for year/month which i do not want. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the WordPress `wp-config.php` file, and then add the following code after `require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-settings.php');` declaration.

```
define( 'UPLOADS' , 'files' );
```

New uploaded files should now be stored in a "files" folder, as shown below.

Copied from: [www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-upload-dir/](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-upload-dir/)

This Works, I have tried it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to make it not do the subdirectories for year/month?